# Почему код выполняется с "чужеродной" строкой?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

[Есть код](https://ideone.com/Fl62p8)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{

    static void example(){

        https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions

        System.out.println("Hellolo!");
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        example();
    }
}
```

Почему вроде как чужеродная строка

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions
```

внутри метода не мешает выполнению программы?

Заметил это в Android Studio. IDE выделяет только `https` с подсказкой

```
Unused label 'https' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Reports unused code labels.
```

Приложение компилируется и запускается

```
String example(){

    https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions

    return "Hello!";
}
```

если из onCreate вызвать

```
if(DEBUG) Log.i("TAG", "example() - " + example() );
```

На выходе

```
I/TAG: example() - Hello!
```

В следующем виде IDE уже ругается и подчеркивает всю строку

```
void example(){

    https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions

}
```

Подсказка - `label without statement`

*Примечание: чужеродная значит ни переменная, ни выражение ... (в моем скудном представлении)*

Comment: @pavlofff: Ха.. чтото не связал в голове. спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что, с точки зрения компилятора вы установили метку (точку безусловного перехода с синтаксисом `label:`) с именем *https* за которой следует комментарий (//).

Во втором случае нет кода, куда бы ссылалась эта метка